# DMA unknown behaviour

Tags: uart, dma, nxp-microcontroller

I am trying to use DMA for LPUART RX and TX for a NXP board(S32K144). I am successfully able to transmit request and receive response. But i get first four bytes of my response with some junk value and then the actual data. I am not able to figure out why am I getting the junk value?
Can anyone tell me what can be the issue?

Comment: At least provide some code to show how freeRTOS is involved in your question, or else remove `freertos` tag from your question.

Answer (score -1):

Check if the array initialization is completed before sending data